# Jquery 'Highlight' element with the same class

Tags: jquery, image, hover

i'm trying to acchive this:

I have something like:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="class-1">Link 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="class-2">Link 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="class-3">Link 3</a></li>
</ul>

<img src="img-desc.jpg" class="class-1" />
<img src="img-desc-1.jpg" class="class-2" />
<img src="img-desc-2.jpg" class="class-3" />
```

I want that everytime the user pass the mouse over one of the the ul>li the image with the matching class gets a red border. How can I acchieve this??

Thanks so much to everyone, I hope you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q7knH/

```
$('ul > li').hover(function() {
    $('img.' + $(this).children('a').attr('class') ).css('border','2px solid red');
},function() {
    $('img.' + $(this).children('a').attr('class') ).css('border','');
});
```

or if you're certain that the `<li>` elements won't have any whitespace around their `<a>`, you could make it a little shorter:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q7knH/1/

```
$('ul > li').hover(function() {
    $('img.' + this.firstChild.className ).css('border','2px solid red');
},function() {
    $('img.' + this.firstChild.className ).css('border','');
});
```

Or if you wanted the hover to take place on the `<a>`, then do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q7knH/3/

```
$('ul > li > a').hover(function() {
    $('img.' + this.className ).css('border','2px solid red');
},function() {
    $('img.' + this.className ).css('border','');
});
```

Comment: Asker might add more functionality in the future by using `$('img.' + this.className).addClass('some_css_class');` Asker could put whatever he wants in `some_css_class` in addition to the red border so to separate functionality and style.

Comment: @puddingfox: I agree. Adding a class with `.addClass()` instead of setting styles directly would be preferred.