# Bi-directional highlighting of elements with same class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 2 lists of items. One is an ordinary `<ul>` and the other is a grid of images wrapped in `<div>`s.

I am looking to highlight the item hovered on both lists that will work in both directions.

So if I hover over `<li>Apple`, both the `<li>Apple` & `<div>Apple` get highlighted. And this should also work in the other direction, if I hover over the `<div>Apple`, both the `<div>Apple` and `<li>Apple` is highlighted.

Notes:

- I am able to add the unique class name to any element. Either the `<li>` & `<div>` or the `<a>` within.
- Highlighting can be either as an `.active` class or inline styling.

Similar to the below question but works in both directions:
[Jquery 'Highlight' element with the same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752018/jquery-highlight-element-with-the-same-class)

```
<ul>
  <li class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-1" href="">Apples</a>
  </li>
  <li class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-2" href="">Pears</a>
  </li>
  <li class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-3" href="">Bananas</a>
  </li>
  <li class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-4" href="">Pineapples</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-1" href="">
      <img scr="">
      Apples
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-2" href="">
      <img scr="">
      Pears
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-3" href="">
      <img scr="">
      Bananas
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="app-hover-select">
    <a class="item-4" href="">
      <img scr="">
      Pineapples
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

My current jQuery with current HTML:

```
        jQuery('.app-hover-select > a').hover(function() {
            var appClass = jQuery(this).attr("class");
            jQuery(appClass).toggleClass('active');
        });
```

My logic is:

1. On hover of `.app-hover-select > a`
2. `var appClass` = Get the class
3. Add class `active` to all elements with the class `appClass`

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: *Similar to [answer] but works in both directions* - then just add it in the other direction.

Comment: By giving both sides the same class you actually made it even easier - just `$(".item-1").hover(() => $(".item1").addClass("hover"), () => $(".item1").removeClass("hover"))` - of course you probably don't want to do this otherwise you have to have 4x the same code (and more if you add more items).  I would add a `data-item="1"` (etc) to both sides and the same code but using `[item=" + $(this).data(item) + "]"` (and not using arrow functions of course)

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersenn Please see above my current attempt.

Comment: Change `jQuery(appClass)` to `jQuery("." + appClass)` to add the class selector.  I would change hover to mouseover and remove active from all active, then you're sorted:  https://jsfiddle.net/d1c97rx4/  (though this may not be the most efficient... so can be tweaked)

Comment: @freedomn-m That is perfect, thank you. I have also added a mouseout function as well. https://codepen.io/essiem/pen/MWvZVRY

Answer (score 1):

In case you want this:

[image]

Try this-

```js
jQuery(".app-hover-select > a").hover(function () {
  const listOfItems = this.parentElement.parentElement;
  const listItem = this.parentElement;
  const i = Array.from(listOfItems.children).indexOf(listItem);

  jQuery("ul .app-hover-select").each((_i, el) => {
    if (_i === i) {
      el.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      el.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
  jQuery(".wrapper .app-hover-select").each((_i, el) => {
    if (_i === i) {
      el.classList.add("active");
    } else {
      el.classList.remove("active");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: This works well, thank you Akul!